# What is the fastest way to scale and display an image in Python?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, image-scaling

I am required to display a two dimensional numpy.array of int16 at 20fps or so. Using Matplotlib's imshow chokes on anything above 10fps. There obviously are some issues with scaling and interpolation. I should add that the dimensions of the array are not known, but will probably be around thirty by four hundred.

These are data from a sensor that are supposed to have a real-time display, so the data has to be re-sampled on the fly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way to display 30x400 data points is to:

### Use OpenGL color arrays

If you can quickly transform your data to what OpenGL understands as color array, you could create a vertex array describing quads, one for each sensor, then update your color array and draw this orthographically on screen.

### Use OpenGL textures

If you can quickly transform your datapoints to an opengl texture you can draw one quad with fixed UV coordinates that is bound to this texture.

### Use pygame

Pygame has support for conversion of Numpy/Numarray to surfaces, Pygame can then transform such surfaces which involves resampling, after resampling you can blit it on screen.

### Misc

[pyglet](http://pyglet.org/) makes dealing with opengl very easy

Comment: Thanks, but the data needs to be re-sampled, since this is a real-time display of sensor data.

Comment: So I get this right. You have an input of say 10x10 sensor points. You want to scale this up to display on a big screen?

Comment: So the question isn't how to resample. It's how to create a big display of your 30x400 data points fast.

Comment: Well, the image needs to be scaled to be more or less squared, but I guess OpenGL could take care of that.

Comment: Yes, you can choose an Orthographic display for opengl.